# How to add increment/decrement indicator in R

Tags: r, icons, data-visualization

I have a datatable and want to add a decrement/increment indicator like an arrow up or down next to the value as a new column. Do you have any suggestions for this code example below? I have calculated the trend below and want to add something like an icon close to the value. When the value is bigger than x, arrow up; when value is smaller than 0, arrow down; when value is 0, then "-".

Comment: If it is only for the visualization purposes, I recommend using package `formattable`. Check this link: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/11/make-beautiful-tables-with-the-formattable-package/     , especially section: Arrows (and hiding columns)

Comment: For some reasons this is not working for me. But I already know this package and it is a really good opportunity. I was thinking about adding a new column where the icons get in. And depending on the if clauses the according icon will be inserted in the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a column of up and down arrows directly in the R console, you will need to use unicode symbols. Since your sample data consists mostly of NA values and doesn't allow all three arrow types to be drawn, I have modified the example to show how this might be achieved. The following code should be fully reproducible with copying and pasting into your console:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(3)

df1 <- data.frame(DATES = seq(as.Date("2020-11-20"), by = "month", length = 13),
                  TREND = round(runif(13, -10, 10)))

df1 %>% 
   mutate(CHANGE = ifelse(TREND < 0, "\u2193",
                          ifelse(TREND == 0, "\u2194", "\u2191"))) %>%
         as.matrix() %>% 
         noquote()

      DATES      TREND CHANGE
 [1,] 2020-11-20 -7    ↓     
 [2,] 2020-12-20  6    ↑     
 [3,] 2021-01-20 -2    ↓     
 [4,] 2021-02-20 -3    ↓     
 [5,] 2021-03-20  2    ↑     
 [6,] 2021-04-20  2    ↑     
 [7,] 2021-05-20 -8    ↓     
 [8,] 2021-06-20 -4    ↓     
 [9,] 2021-07-20  2    ↑     
[10,] 2021-08-20  3    ↑     
[11,] 2021-09-20  0    ↔     
[12,] 2021-10-20  0    ↔     
[13,] 2021-11-20  1    ↑
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with sjPlot:

```
  library(sjPlot)
  df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(symbol = ifelse(TREND > 0, 
                       paste("<p>&#8593;</p>"),NA))
  
  sjPlot::tab_df(df1)
```